# vscode-remote SSH per host default extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When using vscode remote ssh for development, I have different servers that I login to that require different extensions. The servers are transient and often re-created, and when this happens the extensions are lost.

I can use the `remote.SSH.defaultExtensions` setting to globally install extensions, but there are different extensions that are required for different servers. I would like to have a per-host extension customization, or be able to put a file on the remote system that would govern which extensions are installed when connecting for the first time.

Is this possible?